# Real time backup for a modifying directory (e.g. HTTP server)

Tags: shell, backup

Say I am running an HTTP server with data at `/var/www`. I want to backup `/var/www` to `/root/backup/.tmp/var/www` daily automatically.

Mostly the backup is using `rsync` technique. The problem is that since the HTTP server is running, there could be file modification during an rsync backup process.

For an HTTP server a certain "transaction" could involve multiple files, e.g. modifying file A and B at once, and therefore such scenario is possible: rsync backups file A => a transaction occurs and file A and B are modified => rsync backups file B. This causes the backup-ed files to be inconsistent (A is before transaction while B is after transaction).

For an HTTP server shutting down for backup is not viable. Is there a way to avoid such inconsistent file backup?

Answer (score 0):

As its name means, `rsync` command is *syncing* files between *remote* and local. So from what you are describing , you want to backup files locally. So I think a `crontab` job with a shell script will satisfy your demands. A `tar` command may last sometime, but you can split your `/var/www` files into smaller files and use `tar -g` to back up your files increasingly.

As inconsistent problems, I think backing up is a snapshot for files at exactly one time. So at this time, backing up is backing up the current status. After that, some files' changes will be backed up at later time.